# Maven: Including a META-INF folder in the classes folder

Tags: java, web-applications, maven-2, jakarta-ee, maven-plugin

I have a very simple WAR project and I want to include a directory named `META-INF` at the top of the classes output folder where all the compiled Java classes are. 
I'm using Maven, but it seems that by default Maven won't include anything that is not a Java class. So it ignores my `META-INF` directory that is sitting at the top of the `src` directory. 
The `META-INF` directory contains a file named `persistence.xml`. Any quick pointers on how to instruct Maven to put this directory and file into the output folder?

Answer (score 83):

In general, for a Java-based Maven project, non-source files should go in the `src/main/resources` sub-directory of the project. The contents of that `resources` directory are copied to the output directory (by default, `target/classes`) during the *process-resources* phase of the build.

For Maven WAR projects, it is slightly more complicated: there is also the `src/main/webapp` directory, wherein Maven expects to find `WEB-INF/web.xml`. To build your WAR file, that file must exist; otherwise, you'll see an error message like this:

```
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] BUILD ERROR
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Error assembling WAR: webxml attribute is required (or pre-existing WEB-INF/web.xml if executing in update mode)
```

As the `WEB-INF` directory must exist under `src/main/webapp`, I'd recommend avoiding defining it again in `src/main/resources`. Although this is perfectly valid and the contents of the two directories will be merged, it can get confusing if a file is defined in both. The contents of `src/main/resources` will take precedence as they are copied over the top of the contents from `src/main/webapp`.

Comment: Thje original question was actually about META-INF not WEB-INF, although web.xml goes into WEB-INF files such as context.xml are required to be in META-INF, but solution is much the same. Create a META-INF folder within webapp and put context.xml within there.

Answer (score 11):

Maven wants this type of information in the resources folder. See [here](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html) for more information.

```
Project
|-- pom.xml
`-- src
    `-- main
        |-- java
        `-- resources
```

For specifying additional resource directories, see [here](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/resource-directory.html).

Answer (score 4):

I'll indirectly answer your question by saying that if you've already made the jump to Maven2 I'd definitely recommend using the Archetype Plugin.  Using the webapp archetype will ensure you end up with a canonical directory structure.  Anyone else looking at your source will immediiately know where everything is and there won't be any question as to where your files go.

Answer (score 4):

Put this into pom.xml:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

Answer (score 0):

Give the below entry in POM.xml

```
<plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.1.1</version>
                <configuration>
                  <!--webappDirectory>/sample/servlet/container/deploy/directory</webappDirectory-->
                  <packagingExcludes>**/web.xml</packagingExcludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```