# Maven error while building WAR package (web.xml missing..?)

Tags: java, maven-2

While executing `mvn install`, I'm getting following error:

> Error assembling WAR: webxml attribute
>   is required (or pre-existing
>   WEB-INF/web.xml if executing in update
>   mode)

My web application structure tree is like that:

```
my-app
|-- pom.xml
|-- src
    |-- ...
    |-- WebContent
        |-- ...
        |-- META-INF
        |-- WEB-INF
            |-- classes
                |-- ...
            |-- lib
            |-- **web.xml**
```

My POM file looks like that:

```
<project>
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>masters.traffic</groupId>
  <artifactId>traffic_web</artifactId>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <name>traffic_web</name>
  <version>0.1.0</version>
  <build>
        <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.6</source>
                    <target>1.6</target>                    
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
  </build>

    ...
</project>
```

How to properly fix that issue ?

Regards

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I **strongly** recommend to use [Maven's standard layout](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html):

- put the Java sources in `src/main/java` (and remove the `sourceDirectory` element)
- put the Web application sources in `src/main/webapp`
- remove the `classes` and `lib` directories under `WEB-INF`

Sure, you can customize the layout but this is IMO more troubles and useless efforts than benefits. Just follow the conventions.

Comment: Thanks! I've spent a lot of time figuring out why JSF wasn't rendering and I had WEB-INF in a different directory, then, fiddling with the IDEA .iml file I got it working by adding a deployment descriptor for the web.xml, what's weird is that this then stopped working.. I guess now it'll work for good ;)

Answer (score 14):

My guess is that `maven-war-plugin` is looking for `src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/web.xml`, but can't find it, and wants you to specify the (non-maven-standard) location explicitly. If you can't rename `WebContent` to `webapp` and move it under `src/main/` (recommended), you could try adding something like this to your `<build>`

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
  <configuration>
    <webXml>${basedir}/src/WebContent/WEB-INF/web.xml</webXml>
    <warSourceDirectory>${basedir}/src/WebContent</warSourceDirectory>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Comment: What if i have no web.xml  in my web appliction ?

Comment: @Vivek add <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml> to configuration

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this comment:

[Maven: Including a META-INF folder in the classes folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1297473/maven-including-a-meta-inf-folder-in-the-classes-folder/1298573#1298573)

I believe Maven expects a folder called "webapp", not "WebContent".

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue recently and the problem was that my resource class was not specifying an initial path at the top of the class.  Each method specifed a path, but there was nothing specifying the initial path.

Example:

```
@Path("/")
public class MyResource {

@GET
@Produces("text/html")
public String foo() {
    return "foo";
}

@GET
@Path("pt")
@Produces("text/html")
public String bar() {
    return "bar";
}
```

Will work just fine.  But,

```
public class MyResource {

@GET
@Produces("text/html")
public String foo() {
    return "foo";
}

@GET
@Path("pt")
@Produces("text/html")
public String bar() {
    return "bar";
}
```

will not

Answer (score 0):

If you're using eclispe, make sure to right click the project and create a Maven "project." You can compile as a batch from command line with updates using mvn generate:archetype -B -cpu but you might have to manually structure a few things. With this it will run as a web application or a client application. Add this code to pom.xml.

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
            <configuration>
                <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
```